# Incrustar combobox con datos de la base en ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Hola buenos dias tengo un ajax que lo que hace es cargar preguntas en un accordion tengo un campo el cual es un input text que yo escribo algun dato de la base de datos y me manda la info segun si esta incrustrado pero ahora lo que quiero es cambiarlo por un combobox para que las personas puedan ver quienes estan hay y no tener que poner a escribir siempre en el input text me podrian ayudar como hacer para que me los muestre en un combobox
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Cuando finalize el recorrido de los datos recogidos,yo crearía otra función pasándole los datos y apuntaría al elemento `txt_tec_ins_inc`.No se si con este ejemplo te sirve.Si llegas a tener mas select en la creación,yo lo haría recorriendo el DOM seleccionando todos los select dentro de ese contenedor.Espero que te sirva de ayuda

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var datos = ["peter","antonio","juan","Andrés","Javi"];

function rellenaCampos(datos){
    $.each(datos,function(i,e){
     $("#txt_tec_ins_inc").append('<option value="'+ e +'">'+ e +'</option>');
     
    })
   
   };
   
  function rellenarSelects(){
   
      $("#caja").append('<select class="form-control" id="txt_tec_ins_inc"></select>');
   
    rellenaCampos(datos);
  };
  rellenarSelects();
});
```

```css
div{
margin-left:200px;
}

#txt_tec_ins_inc{
width:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="caja"></div>
```